# Is JSONObject supported in OpenJDK 8?

Tags: java, json

I have a `json-lib-2.2-jdk15.jar` library on my classpath, but it does not work as expected in the following code:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(); // I import this as org.json.JSONObject;
jsonObj.put("UserName", "PETER");
jsonObj.put("Age", "20");
sName = jsonObj.toString();
writeLog(logFile, "JSON value is:" + sName + "\n");
```

It returns `sName = null` while I expect it to return `sName = {"UserName":"PETER","Age":"20"}`.

Is the code wrong or does JSONObject not work with OpenJDK 8?

Comment: Edit your code please, and provide this information there.

Comment: According to [SOURCEFORGE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/json-lib/files/json-lib/json-lib-2.2.2/) that JAR file is from the year 2008 which means it was created before Java 1.7 was released. Would you consider using a more up-to-date and popular JSON parser like [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)?

Comment: due to system limitation, i need to revise existing code to support openjdk8 (upgrade from jrun4) and output result in json format. Since above code works under jrun4. I have no idea how to revise the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json-lib-2.2-jdk15.jar` is a release of 2008, which is very old, and which is no longer supported.

You can use [JSON-Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20200518) (*reference implementation*) instead (if you do not want to use *Jackson*, *GSON* or something more popular), and this code:

```
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("UserName", "PETER");
    jsonObj.put("Age", "20");
    String sName = jsonObj.toString();
    System.out.println(sName);
```

will output:

```
{"UserName":"PETER","Age":"20"}
```

<sub>If you want to download the `.jar` file alternative of the JSON-Java, you can do it from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20200518/json-20200518.jar).</sub>

Comment: my code already same as your, but not work. which jar library file should i download for openjdk? thanks.

Comment: Just click on the JSON-Java text I have provided in my answer, or click [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20200518/json-20200518.jar) to get this dependency as a `jar` file.

Comment: many thanks for your help. its work when i use your jar file instead of json-lib-2.2-jdk15.jar one. may i know is this official release version? Thanks.